# Didn't find class "android.view.fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm getting the errors:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:
>   Error inflating class fragment Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.rankov.maplistener-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

On this line

```
inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_maps, this);
```

Here is my xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.rankov.maplistener.MapsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult"
            android:text="@string/done" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</fragment>
```

Here is my view

```
public class MapsView extends FrameLayout implements OnMapReadyCallback, PlaceSelectionListener, View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "qwe";
    private Maps maps;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment;
    private Button button_done;

    private Location userLocation;

    public MapsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_maps, this);

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity) getContext();
        FragmentManager fm = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentManager fm2 = fragmentActivity.getFragmentManager();

        //mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) (Object) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                fm2.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        button_done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_done);
        button_done.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Started with this activity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_view);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.test_layout);
        MapsView mView = new MapsView(getApplicationContext());
        layout.addView(mView);
}
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: please check if all the fragment references are either View.fragment or support.v4.app.Fragment  and not a mix between both

Comment: @SarahMaher i import only PlaceAutocompleteFragment and SupportMapFragment;

also i use different FragmentManagers for this fragments (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager and android.app.FragmentManager). is it ok?